# Who echos the characters in terminal?

Tags: c, io, terminal

Lets look at the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
             char c;

             while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                     putchar(c);

             return (0);
 }
```

This program echo's back the characters, only after a new line is passed as a character.
I tried directly reading using the read system call and passing len as 1, it still reads only when a new line is passed. I have 2 questions here: Who has implemented this optimization, is it the kernel or the terminal/shell?

Secondly, who is echoing back the characters on the first place, that is on the first press itself. Does terminal/shell play any role in the entire execution of this program?

Comment: I understand the shell is somewhat responsible: the program behaves differently when you call it with or without redirections: `./a.out` vs `./a.out < input.txt > output.txt` vs ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell is irrelevant.  The tty into which you type (assuming it is not in raw mode, and echoing is enabled ) displays the characters as you type them, but does not pass them to the process until after you type enter.  It handles all backspaces and editing etc, and your process never sees those.  When you hit enter, the tty passes the entered line to the process.

Answer (score 1):

When a task is being executed(for example your program), it is in "RUNNING" state.

At the time when the program requests keyboard input, the kernel suspends your program and wires the keyboard input to a buffer in the program memory(maintained by the LDT and GDT registers in IA32 arch)

The keyboard data is read with specific interrupt functions in the IVT(Interrupt Vector Table)(this table is maintained using IDTs in IA32 Arch)

When a new line is encountered(by pressing ENTER key on your keyboard), the input buffer is closed, the task is brought from "suspended" state to "ready" state.

A multitasking kernel hardly has the "time" to wait for user input and echo it back to the output. Instead, it wires the keyboard to a buffer and goes away to do other important tasks(such as task scheduling). When a program is in "running" state, and the keyboard buffer is filled, it reads the input from the buffer, and write it to the output buffer.

The Shell however, is just a program that is being scheduled by the kernel. It has no direct access to the keyboard, but has access to the specific keyboard buffer alloted by the kernel.

Comment: Whilst the LDTR and GDTR have to be set for a program [or the OS] to run, it has relatively little to do with how the keyboard is buffered, as that is just like any other piece of data in memory [unless you are running OS/2 1.x - but I'm guessing not many of the people who ask this type of question are!]

Comment: @MatsPetersson I learnt this technique when I wrote my own toy OS. But I think the whole buffering is upto the stdlib implementor.

Comment: Also, "keyboard input" isn't always from the keyboard. For example, if I use SSH to connect to another computer, the input goes via a network cable to the other side, and the process reading the "keyboard" is actually reading from a pseudo-tty, which is fed by the `sshd` daemon. Similarly, if you have a `xterm` shell, rather than a VGA or FB screen in Linux, the keyboard input goes via a pseudoterminal

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am hoping the pseudoterminal then emulates a keystroke.

Comment: stdlib is not where this is (typically) implemented, but in the keyboard driver. If you call read with a zero as the file-descriptor, it will still buffer the input. And read is not implemented in the C-library.

Comment: no i mean stdlib of the kernel(which also includes the driver)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "emultates keystroke". It allows you to read the data in a fashion of a regular terminal - exactly how the data got there is up to the OS to figure out. If you are explaining how this happens in "your own OS", that's only really useful if people are asking about how it works in your OS. I'm describing how it works in Linux and most other Unix's. Windows works similarly but doesn't really have pseudoterminals.

Comment: Please try to use common names for things in the same way that other people use them - it makes life so much easier. stdlib is the C library by most peoples meanings. If I start calling my bicycle a car, does that mean that all other people understand what I mean when I say I got here by car?

Comment: well I am not explaining how it happens in my own OS, the question was pretty straight forward, is it the kernel or the shell that does this kind of buffering. And I have only one thing to tell him, the shell has no direct access to the keyboard..

Comment: Unless, the shell is running in ring0(kernel) mode, and has access to ports.